# How can I append hidden input to this file input after jquery simpleUpload success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Trying to append a hidden form field after the file input that was used to upload a file within the simpleUpload call.

HTML (dynamicly loaded):

```
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Image Upload</label>
            <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control upfile" placeholder="image upload">
        </div>
    </div>
```

So far I have tried:

```
$(document).on('change', '.upfile', function(){
    var obj = $(this);
    $(this).simpleUpload("/upload.php", {
        start: function(file){ console.log("upload started"); },
        progress: function(progress){ console.log("upload progress: " + Math.round(progress) + "%"); },
        success: function(data){
            $(obj).append('<input type="text" name="images[]" value="'+data.message+'">');
            console.log("upload successful!");
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(error){ console.log("upload error: " + error.name + ": " + error.message); }
    });
});
```

```
$(document).on('change', '.upfile', function(){
    var obj = this;
    $(this).simpleUpload("/upload.php", {
        start: function(file){ console.log("upload started"); },
        progress: function(progress){ console.log("upload progress: " + Math.round(progress) + "%"); },
        success: function(data){
            $(obj).append('<input type="text" name="images[]" value="'+data.message+'">');
            console.log("upload successful!");
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(error){ console.log("upload error: " + error.name + ": " + error.message); }
    });
});
```

To no avail. There seems to be no way of setting a context: in simpleUpload or I would have tried that.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by **hidden**? 

Comment: <input type="hidden">

Comment: I have 2 questions at this line: `$(obj).append('<input type="text" name="images[]" value="'+data.message+'">');` 1. Why do you write `type=text`? 2. Is `images[]`the name? 

Comment: I used type="text" just so I could see if it appeared. yes images[] is the name

Comment: Do you have tried `$(obj).parent().append('<input type="text" name="images[]" value="'+data.message+'">');`? 

Comment: made no difference

Comment: Can i see your HTML structure, please?

Comment: added above in question

Comment: Please have a look. Is this the desired outcome https://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/hq39gu0L/5/ ?

Comment: You MAY have a look at `delegated handler` https://stackoverflow.com/a/8111171/2569323 .

Answer (score 0):

Understanding your question, you're seeking to dynamically add a hidden input field to your form after successfully uploading a file using the simpleUpload plugin in jQuery. You've attempted appending this input directly to the file input element, but this approach has not produced the desired outcome. This is because, as per HTML standards, an input element cannot contain other elements, including another input.

To achieve your goal, you can insert the hidden input field as a sibling to the file input element rather than as a child. This method involves using jQuery's `.after()` method, which inserts content directly after the selected element in the DOM. Here's how you can modify your existing code:

```
$(document).on('change', '.upfile', function() {
  var fileInput = $(this); // Cache the jQuery object of the file input
  fileInput.simpleUpload("/upload.php", {
    start: function(file) {
      console.log("upload started");
    },
    progress: function(progress) {
      console.log("upload progress: " + Math.round(progress) + "%");
    },
    success: function(data) {
      // Insert a hidden input field right after the file input element
      fileInput.after('<input type="hidden" name="images[]" value="' + data.message + '">');
      console.log("upload successful!");
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log("upload error: " + error.name + ": " + error.message);
    }
  });
});
```

Key Points:

- Method Used: The `.after()` jQuery method is utilized to insert the hidden input immediately following the file input element, thus adhering to the correct HTML structure.
- Input Type: I've specified the type of the newly inserted input as "hidden" to match your requirement of it being a hidden field. If you need to verify its presence or value for debugging purposes, you can temporarily change its type to "text".
- Dynamic Value Assignment: The value of the hidden input is dynamically set to data.message, which is assumed to be the response from your server-side script (`/upload.php`) indicating a successful upload.

This solution adheres to specifications by providing a viable alternative to your initial approach. It directly addresses your goal of appending a hidden input after a file input upon a successful upload without altering the fundamental behavior of your application. This method ensures that the form dynamically includes the data necessary for server-side processing or subsequent JavaScript manipulation, aligning with best practices in web development.

Comment: thanks, and this looks like it should work, but also did not.